# Find grouped records in one table that are being matched in another table

Tags: sql, hive

I have two tables like below in Hive

Table 1:

```
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| id | subject  |   date   |     amount|
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
|  1 | Do this  | 10-10-13 |     20985 |
|  2 | Done this| 10-10-13 |     18657 |
|  3 | Dont do  | 12-12-13 |     22039 |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
```

Table 2:

```
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| id | subject  |   date   |     amount|
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
|  1 | Do this  | 10-10-13 |     10985 |
|  2 | Done this| 10-10-13 |     18657 |
|  3 | Dont do  | 12-12-13 |     22039 |
|  4 | Do this  | 10-10-13 |     10000 |
|  5 | Did this | 11-10-13 |     30000 |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
```

When I `group by subject and date` on both tables then for records where `subject and date are Do this and 10-10-13` I get the sum(amount) as same.

Now I want to find the records in `table 2` that are being grouped to match the grouped amounts in `table 1`.

The result I want is

```
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| id | subject  |   date   |     amount|
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
|  1 | Do this  | 10-10-13 |     10985 |
|  2 | Done this| 10-10-13 |     18657 |
|  3 | Dont do  | 12-12-13 |     22039 |
|  4 | Do this  | 10-10-13 |     10000 |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
```

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: why the id = 4 is in the result list ?

Comment: @Simonare - Because *10985 + **10000**  = 20985*. The SUM for ('Do this', '10-10-13') group is the same in both tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select t2.*
from (select t2.*,
             sum(amount) over (partition by date, subject) as total_amount
      from table2 t2
     ) t2 join
     table1 t1
     on t1.date = t2.date and t2.subject = t2.subject and t1.amount = t2.total_amount
```

Comment: You answer works for the question. I got a small doubt What if the table one has been derived as a result of a group by on date and subject columns from another table. How we can deal then?

Comment: Use a CTE or subquery.

Comment: I have added a query in the question can you please have a look.

Comment: @user10140821 . . . Use a CTE.